# Shell script for loop outputs unordered sequence of numbers

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote shell script like this below and outputs like

```
redis-health-checker: Ping failed 1
redis-health-checker: Ping failed 3
redis-health-checker: Ping failed 2
```

but It was supposed to output like

```
redis-health-checker: Ping failed 1
redis-health-checker: Ping failed 2
redis-health-checker: Ping failed 3
```

( This script is a simple check-script to see if redis-server is alive or not and tell Keepalived if it stops working. )

```
#!/bin/bash

for TRIES in $(seq 1 3)
do
  RESULT=$($REDIS_CLI ping)
  if [ "${/etc/redis-cli}" = "PONG" ]; then
    exit 0
  fi
  echo "Ping failed ${TRIES}" | logger -t redis-health-checker
  sleep 1
done

exit 1 # Makes Keepalived FALL
```

Comment: What's the exact output?  It doesn't seem possible for your script to output `1, 3, 2` or even `1, 2, 3` for that matter.

Comment: @Mr.Klama sorry updated!

Comment: These are not directly related to the problem you're seeing, but (1) use `for blah in {1..3}`; (2) `"${/etc/redis-cli}"` makes no sense at all.